# Error in tkz-euclide?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I have some code generating a triangle as below:

```
\nonstopmode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc, intersections, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\changefontsizes[12pt]{10pt}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{red_1}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\section*{\centering{Question Sheet}}
\vspace{10mm}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,thick]
\coordinate (B) at (2.5,5.5);
\coordinate (A) at (-1,9.0);
\coordinate (C) at (-4,-1.0);
\tkzMarkAngle[size=3cm,color=red_1,line width=1.5,opacity=0.5](B,C,A);
\tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.5,color=red_1,line width=1,opacity=0.5](A,B,C);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\node at (-3.1609768069701802,0.4047040536671167) {$28.3\degree$};
\node[above,color=black] at (-2.5,4.0) {$$10.4$cm\hspace{40pt}$};
\node[below,color=black] at (-0.75,2.25) {$\hspace{40pt}$9.2$cm$};
\node[right,color=black] at (2.5,5.5) {$$B$$};
\node[below,color=black] at (-4.0,-1.0) {$$C$\hspace{20pt}$};
\node[above,color=black] at (-1.0,9.0) {$$A$$};
\end{tikzpicture}\\




\end{document}
```

but when I compile it, the `\tkzMarkAngle[size=3cm,color=red_1,line width=1.5,opacity=0.5](B,C,A);` throws the errors "Missing number, treated as zero. ...=red_1,line width=1.5,opacity=0.5](B,C,A)" and "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...=red_1,line width=1.5,opacity=0.5](B,C,A)". I can't see where these are coming from, and I have another 9 triangles written with identical structure, and only the values of the points and labels changing and they work fine. What is causing this?

Here's a picture of the triangle:

[image]

and one of the others:

[image]

and the code for the second triangle:

```
\nonstopmode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc, intersections, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\changefontsizes[12pt]{10pt}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{red_1}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\section*{\centering{Question Sheet}}
\vspace{10mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,thick]
\coordinate (A) at (-3.076923076923077,8.384615384615385);
\coordinate (C) at (-2,3.0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,9.8);
\tkzMarkAngle[size=2cm,color=red_1,line width=1.5,opacity=0.5](A,B,C);
\tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.5,color=red_1,line width=1,opacity=0.5](C,A,B);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\node at (2.9151888829770587,9.175118149666678) {$37.3\degree$};
\node[below,color=black] at (1.0,6.4) {$\hspace{40pt}$9.1$cm$};
\node[above,color=black] at (0.46153846153846156,9.092307692307692) {$$7.2$cm\hspace{40pt}$};
\node[left,color=black] at (-3.076923076923077,8.384615384615385) {$$A$$};
\node[above,color=black] at (4.0,9.8) {$\hspace{20pt}$B$$};
\node[below,color=black] at (-2.0,3.0) {$$C$$};
\end{tikzpicture}\\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure why that happens (the error message looked like it came from some calculation involving `atan`), but you can use the features of the `angles` and `quotes` libraries of TikZ instead, and do

```
\pic[draw,red,angle eccentricity=0.75,angle radius=2.5cm,"\ang{28.3}" text=black] {angle=B--C--A};
```

In the code below I suggest a modification of the code. Labels for corners are added as a `label` for the `coordinate`, instead of separate nodes at explicit coordinates. Labels for sides are added as nodes placed during the drawing of the sides, again instead of separate nodes at explicit coordinates.

I used `siunitx` to typeset both the angle (`\ang{28.3}`) and the lengths (`\SI{9.1}{\cm}`). The way the lengths were typeset was actually wrong, with the unit in math italics. And the `\hspace` in a couple of the nodes is not really necessary, one can place the node better instead.

The two triangles looks like this with the code below:

[image: triangles from code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\definecolor{red_1}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}

% redefine \section instead of manually adding \centering
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\centering}
\begin{document}
\section*{Question Sheet}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,thick]
\coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (2.5,5.5);
\coordinate [label=above:$A$] (A) at (-1,9.0);
\coordinate [label=below:$C$] (C) at (-4,-1.0);

% mark angle
\pic[draw,red_1,angle eccentricity=0.75,angle radius=2.5cm,"\ang{28.3}" text=black] {angle=B--C--A};

\tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.5,color=red_1,line width=1,opacity=0.5](A,B,C);

\draw (A) -- 
      (B) -- node[below right] {\SI{9.2}{\cm}} 
      (C) -- node[above left] {\SI{10.4}{\cm}} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,thick]
\coordinate [label=above left:$A$] (A) at (-3.076923076923077,8.384615384615385);
\coordinate [label=below:$C$] (C) at (-2,3.0);
\coordinate [label=above right:$B$] (B) at (4,9.8);

\tkzMarkAngle[size=2cm,color=red_1,line width=1.5,opacity=0.5](A,B,C);
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](A,B,C) {\ang{37.3}}

\tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.5,color=red_1,line width=1,opacity=0.5](C,A,B);

\draw (A) -- node[above left] {\SI{7.2}{\cm}}
      (B) -- node[below right] {\SI{9.1}{\cm}}
      (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```